# How to get current url in any browser in android?

Tags: android, browser, webview

I am trying that any user must see just my WebView and my webpage. If user close my WebView application, he/she must not be allowed to go to another webpage in any other browser. That's why I need to get current web page url. If current webpage url equals to my web page url, it is good. But if not, current webpage must not be work, instead reload and display my webpage. Can I get current url in any browser in Android?

Comment: You can get current URL or browsing history from Default browser. But not from other browsers such as Firefox for Android or Opera etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last visited URL from the `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` database

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
        Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
cursor.moveToNext();
String url = cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
cursor.close();
```